# 2002 sunfire - should I change trans fluid

Tags: automatic-transmission, car

Got a 2002 sunfire from my dad with 103K on it.  Now 111K.  Never had trans fluid changed - should I do it or not ?

Manual says not needed unless rough service - While in my dads care it was easy service.

Answer (score 1):

111K miles and 18 years?  Yes, change the fluid and the filter too.